# Is $(-1)^x$ a Function of $x$ if domain is a set of natural numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $(-1)^x$ a Function of $x$ if domain is a set of natural numbers? If yes, what kind of function is it and how to differentiate it?

---

By definition, a function is a rule that assigns to each element $x$ of the domain exactly one element called $f(x)$.

Comment: Sure.  If $x$ is odd, then $(-1)^x = -1$.  If $x$ is even, then $(-1)^x = 1$.  But, it doesn't have a derivative, at least in the usual sense, because it is discrete.

Comment: On the natural numbers the role of derivatives is played by the notion of [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Rules_for_calculus_of_finite_difference_operators). To consider proper derivatives the points of the domain shouldn't be isolated as in the natural numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Definition**:
>   $f\subset A\times B$ is a function iff $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}:\exists!y\in B:(x,y)\in f$, we write $y=f(x)$ for this unique $y$.

Let $A$ be the set of natural numbers. $A=\Bbb{N}$, and let $B=\{-1,1\}$. We can define your function $f:A\rightarrow B$ as follows:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
      -1, & \text{if}\ x \ \text{is odd}\\
      1, & \text{if}\ x \ \text{is even}\\
    \end{cases}$$
Trivially, every $x\in \Bbb{N}$ is either odd or even (and not both) so we have an unique value for all possible entries.

Differentiability: Because your function is discrete, not continuous, is is not differentiable.

Comment: As stated, that function is continuous. It is not differentiable because differentiability only makes real sense on an open interval or at least a set with a limit point.  The relative topology of the natural numbers inherited from the line is indeed the discrete one.

Comment: True, when considering topology of natural numbers it is continuous. I was considering it in reals.

Comment: You can't.  It is not defined for non-integral values.